# Airflow:Pass data from operator to stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

The requirement is to pass data from the operator to the SQL file, reason is to have run within the same session of the temp table so that it is accessed by the stored procedure in the same session.

I tried two different ways but in vain.

Below is the part of the function in the operator:

```
def list_of_tuples(self, worksheet):
        list_of_dicts = worksheet.get_all_records()
        reviewed_rows = [row for row in list_of_dicts]

        manual_data = [
            (
                str(row["NAME"]),
                str(row["VERSION"]),
                row.get("RSCORE", None),
                row["SERVERDATE"],
            )
            for row in reviewed_rows
        ]

        return manual_data

    def run_proc(self, manual_data):
        source_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=self.source_conn_id)
       
        with closing(source_hook.get_conn()) as source_conn:
            with closing(source_conn.cursor(DictCursor)) as cur:
                try:
                    cur.execute(self.sql, manual_data)
```

This is the SQL file:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
    -- Create a temporary table to store manual_map data
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_manual_map (
        name STRING,
        version STRING,
        score NUMBER,
        serverdate DATE
    );

    -- Insert the data from connector_mapping_manual into the temporary table
    INSERT INTO temp_manual_map
    VALUES :manual_map;
END;
$$;
```

Errors for this SQL file:

```
[2023-10-18, 18:23:10 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1909} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/airflow/operators/con_mapping.py", line 95, in run_proc:
    cur.execute(self.sql, manual_data)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 772, in execute
    query = self._preprocess_pyformat_query(command, params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 604, in _preprocess_pyformat_query
    query = command % processed_params
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Sample data of list manual_map data

```
 [('ECP', None, 64,  '2023-10-15'), ('SX.e 6.2.311 ', '', 59, 1, '2023-10-15')]
```

I also tried this code:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_manual_map (
        name STRING,
        version STRING,
        score INT,
        serverdate DATE
    );

    INSERT INTO manual_map (
        name,
        version,
        score,
        serverdate
    )
    VALUES
    {% for value in :manual_map %}
        (
            '{{ value[0] }}',
            '{{ value[1] }}',
            {{ value[2] }},
            '{{ value[3] }}'
        ){% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %};

END;
$$;
```

And got this error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected ':'

Also tried as below to see if it is able to pass data from operator to the SQL file

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN

    manual_map;

END;
```

Got error as

```
    query = command % processed_params
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

See documentation on [data binding](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#binding-data) in Snowflake Python connector. It's not like simple text replacement - it acts on literals, while you attempt to provide entire structure (multiple records, multiple columns).

Instead of binding construct the values as string and replace the placeholder in SQL using Python function:

```
values = ",".join([f"('{r[0]}', '{r[1]}', {r[2]}, '{r[3]}')" for r in manual_data])
cur.execute(self.sql.replace(":manual_data", values))
```

Comment: I got an error 

```snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): 01afd82a-0806-e2cb-0000-126de8b787e6: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 19 at position 11 unexpected 'INTO'.
syntax error line 19 at position 36 unexpected '.'.```

Comment: Review the resulting SQL text after replace. What you have in the question is 14 lines long, while the error says line 19 - apparently that's something else (unless there are newlines in values maybe...?)